# glb model cant be accessed after build - Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, vite

I imported a model using GLTFLoader and it works perfectly with `npm run dev` but when I build it with `npx vite build` it doesn't seem to be able to access the model file. the file is stored at /public/models/miku_pde.glb

npm run dev:
[image: run with npm run dev]

after build:
[image: after build]

this is the part of the code used for importing the model

```js
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

let model;
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
const modelPath = "/models/miku_pde.glb";

loader.load(modelPath, (gltf) => {
  model = gltf.scene;
  model.position.y = -15;
  scene.add(model);
});
```

i expected the model to show. I tried to make sure the path was correct but it always didn't work after build

Answer (score 1):

Move the glb to src/models/models/,and never use the public folder if you want free from worry

```js
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';
import modelPath from  "@/assets/models/miku_pde.glb?url";
let model;
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
loader.load(modelPath, (gltf) => {
  model = gltf.scene;
  model.position.y = -15;
  scene.add(model);
});
```